# Realm throws exception with empty unit test

Tags: objective-c, swift, unit-testing, realm

In an Objective-C project, we started writing our new Unit Tests in Swift. I'm just now trying to create our first Unit Test of successfully saving the results of a parsed JSON. However, the test already fails during setup() due to the following error:

```
[ProjectTests.Project testInitializingOverlayCollectionCreatesAppropriateRealmObjects] : failed: caught "NSInvalidArgumentException", "+[RLMObjectBase ignoredProperties]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x759b70
```

So apparently it tries to execute `ignoredProperties` on the `RLMObjectBase` class, and that method isn't implemented yet. Not sure how this happens, because I have yet to initialise anything, beyond creating a `RLMRealms` object with a random in-memory identifier.

**ProjectTests.swift**

```
import XCTest

class ProjectOverlayCollectionTests: XCTestCase {

    var realm: RLMRealm!

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()

        // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
        let realmConfig = RLMRealmConfiguration()
        realmConfig.inMemoryIdentifier = NSUUID().UUIDString
        do {
            realm = try RLMRealm(configuration: realmConfig) // <-- Crashes here.
        }
        catch _ as NSError {
            XCTFail()
        }
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
        super.tearDown()
    }

    func testInitializingOverlayCollectionCreatesAppropriateRealmObjects() {
        XCTAssertTrue(true)
    }

}
```

**Project-Bridging-Header.h**

```
#import <Realm/Realm.h>
```

**Podfile**

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '7.1'

def shared_pods
    pod 'Realm', '0.95.0'
end

target 'Project' do
    shared_pods
end    

target 'ProjectTests' do
    shared_pods
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Realm documentation](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#testing);

> Avoid Linking Realm and Tested Code in Test Target

Remove the Realm pod from the `ProjectTests` target and all is right with the world.

**Update:** This answer is outdated. As @rommex mentions in a comment, following the current Realm installation documentation should link it to both your module and test targets without problems. However, I have not checked this.

Comment: This answer is obsolete and wrong now (Realm 4.x) as the documentation states: `In your Podfile, add use_frameworks! and pod 'RealmSwift' to your main and test targets.`

Comment: @rommex Thanks for the comment. While I haven't checked this myself, I did update my answer to point this out to others.